# whmcs javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, html, whmcs

I try to use some javascript for my WHMCS page, when i use it on a normal page without WHMCS it works fine.
But when i add it to a WHMCS page and use {literal} and {/literal} it dosnt work at all.

This is my javascript:

```
{literal}<script type="text/javascript" src="js-d/universal/jquery.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script src="js-d/style-switcher/jquery-1.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script src="js-d/style-switcher/styleselector.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script src="js-d/mainmenu/bootstrap.min.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script src="js-d/mainmenu/customeUI.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script type="text/javascript" src="js-d/mainmenu/sticky.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script type="text/javascript" src="js-d/mainmenu/modernizr.custom.75180.js"></script>{/literal}
{literal}<script src="js-d/scrolltotop/totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not require literal statements for external javascript files. Only for inline javascript.
Check that your file path is correct for the files too

Answer (score 0):

What is not working?
It might be that the path to the javascript files are not correct when you reference from your whmcs page?!

Checkout template variables that you might have use for: http://docs.whmcs.com/Template_Syntax